# Failed to connect to the host via ssh: Permission denied

Tags: google-cloud-platform, ssh, ansible

i am new to ansible
i have installed ansible on ec2 instance (as a master VM)
and now i want to setup my target node as a gcp vm
so for that i have created a gcp vm and update the inventory file

```
ansible-target ansible_host=gcp_vm_ip ansible_connection=ssh ansible_user=apigeehybrid
```

but when i run `ansible ansible-target -m ping`
i got error

```
<35.184.210.81> ESTABLISH SSH CONNECTION FOR USER: apigeehybrid
<35.184.210.81> SSH: EXEC ssh -C -o ControlMaster=auto -o ControlPersist=60s -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o KbdInteractiveAuthentication=no -o PreferredAuthentications=gssapi-with-mic,gssapi-keyex,hostbased,publickey -o PasswordAuthentication=no -o 'User="apigeehybrid"' -o ConnectTimeout=10 -o ControlPath=/root/.ansible/cp/ef74ba60db 35.184.210.80 '/bin/sh -c '"'"'echo ~apigeehybrid && sleep 0'"'"''
<35.184.210.81> (255, '', 'Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic).\r\n')
target-aio | UNREACHABLE! => {
    "changed": false, 
    "msg": "Failed to connect to the host via ssh: Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic).", 
    "unreachable": true
}
```

now i knew i have to use SSH key something but i am a bit confuse becuase i tried a lot method of create key and put on somewhere but that not gonna work in my case

can anyone please elabore the perfect setup to established a connection b/w master vm(ec2) to target vm(gcp instance) that would be great...

Terraform X Apigee integration
the architecture would be same but i have create a node.tf file in master vm of ec2

```
resource "google_compute_network" "default" {
  name = "my-network"
}

resource "google_compute_subnetwork" "default" {
  name          = "my-subnet"
  ip_cidr_range = "10.0.0.0/16"
  region        = "us-central1"
  network       = google_compute_network.default.id
}

resource "google_compute_address" "internal_ip" {
  name         = "my-internal-address"
  project      = var.projectname
  subnetwork   = google_compute_subnetwork.default.id
  address_type = "INTERNAL"
  address      = "10.0.1.0"
  region       = "us-central1"
  purpose      = "GCE_ENDPOINT"
}

resource "google_compute_address" "static" {
  name    = "vm-public-address"
  project = var.projectname
  region  = "us-central1"
}

resource "google_compute_firewall" "firewall2" {
  name    = "gritfy-firewall-externalssh2"
  network = google_compute_network.default.name
  allow {
    protocol = "tcp"
    ports    = ["22"]
  }
  source_ranges = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
}

output "ip1" {
  value = google_compute_address.static.address
}

resource "google_compute_instance" "node1" {
  project        = var.projectname
  name           = "node1"
  machine_type   = "custom-8-16384" //10 core and 20GB of ram custom-10-20480
  zone           = "us-central1-a"
  can_ip_forward = true
  boot_disk {
    initialize_params {
      image = "centos-cloud/centos-7"
    }
  }
  network_interface {
    subnetwork = google_compute_subnetwork.default.id
    network_ip = google_compute_address.internal_ip.address
    access_config {
      nat_ip = google_compute_address.static.address
    }
  }
  metadata = {
    ssh-keys = "${var.user}:${file(var.publickeypath)}"
  }
  lifecycle {
    ignore_changes = [attached_disk]
  }
  provisioner "file" {
    source      = "perquisites.sh"
    destination = "/tmp/perquisites.sh"
    connection {
      host        = google_compute_address.static.address
      type        = "ssh"
      user        = var.user
      private_key = file(var.privatekeypath)
    }
  }
  provisioner "local-exec" {
    command = "echo ${google_compute_address.static.address} > inventory "
  }
  provisioner "local-exec" {
    command = "ssh-keygen -R ${google_compute_address.static.address}"
  }
  provisioner "local-exec" {
    command = "ansible-playbook /root/playbooks/aio.yaml"
  }
}

resource "google_compute_attached_disk" "default3" {
  disk     = google_compute_disk.default2.id
  instance = google_compute_instance.node1.id
}

resource "google_compute_disk" "default2" {
  name  = "disk1"
  type  = "pd-balanced"
  zone  = "us-central1-a"
  image = "centos-7-v20210609"
  size  = 100 //in GBs 300
}
```

and here is ansible.cfg file

```
[defaults]
inventory = ./inventory
deprecation_warnings=False
remote_user = rohan
host_key_checking = False
private_key_file = ./lastkey

[privilege_escalation]
become = true
become_method = sudo
become_user = root
become_ask_pass = False
```

if anyone notices in terraform code I have used remote-exec and that is working I can see a log showing connected

but in ansible, it is showing

[image: logs]

Comment: Are you able to establish a connection between your EC2 and GCE instance via "pure" `ssh`?

Comment: @Sebastian no i am not able to do so even

Comment: Ok then we need some more information: 1. does the user `apigeehybrid` exist on the GCE instance? 2. have you added the public key to `~apigeehybrid/.ssh/authorized_keys`?

Comment: @Sebastian thanks for the quick update i am able to do ssh through my ec2 master vm (i have create a key and pass the comment as mykey  and copy this public key and paste into gcp ssh key  then now i am able to ssh as a mykey)

Comment: so a `ssh apigeehybrid@<your gcp instance>` now works? What about your ansible call?

Comment: i am able to ssh through ssh mykey@<ip> and also now ansible ping pong status thank

Comment: @Sebastian - Can you compile your comments and post them as an answer?

Comment: @Sebastian hey i got that error again i have integrated terraform with anisble but while ansible part run i got that error again although i have created a key and paste them in gcp metadata i am able to ssh through vm but not able to through ansible

Comment: @user16821057 same error with the same ansible call, but you can login to your GCP instance via plain ssh?

Comment: @Sebastian yes correct with ansible there is a issue but while i do plain ssh is working although i have update my question please have a look

Comment: @user16821057 what is the value of `var.user`?

Comment: @Sebastian var.user=rohan

Comment: I created a complete test setup now and what should i say - it worked as expected. What keyfile did you use when you connect via plain ssh? `./lastkey`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/242722/discussion-between-sebastian-and-user16821057).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on the informations you gave us and the error message (`Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic)`) you provided, you need to [create a SSH key pair](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/connect/create-ssh-keys) like

`ssh-keygen -t ed25519 -f ~/.ssh/<KEY_FILENAME> -C <USER>`

(for a full list of options see: https://man.openbsd.org/ssh-keygen)

and then add the **PUBLIC KEY** (not the private key) to the *apigeehybrid* user on your GCE instance, either manually by putting it into the `~apigeehybrid/.ssh/authorized_keys` file or the [GCP native ways](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/connect/add-ssh-keys) like:

##### OS Login

```
gcloud compute os-login ssh-keys add \
    --key-file=KEY_FILE_PATH \
    --project=PROJECT \
    --ttl=EXPIRE_TIME
```

#### Metadata

Run the gcloud compute instances describe command to get the metadata for the VM:

```
gcloud compute instances describe VM_NAME
```

Replace VM_NAME with the name of the VM for which you need to add or remove public SSH keys.

The output is similar to the following:

```
...
metadata:
...
- key: ssh-keys
  value: |-
    cloudysanfrancisco:ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAADAQABAAABAQDAu5kKQCPF...
    baklavainthebalkans:ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAADAQABAAABgQDQDx3FNVC8... google-ssh {"userName":"baklavainthebalkans","expireOn":"2021-06-14T16:59:03+0000"}
...
```

Copy the ssh-keys metadata value.

Create and open a new text file on your workstation.

In the file, paste the list of keys that you just copied.

Add your new key at the end of the list, in one of the following formats:

Format for a key without an expiration time:

```
USERNAME:KEY_VALUE
```

Format for a key with an expiration time:

```
USERNAME:KEY_VALUE google-ssh {"userName":"USERNAME","expireOn":"EXPIRE_TIME"}
```

Replace the following:

**KEY_VALUE**: the public SSH key value

**USERNAME**: the username for the SSH key, specified when the key was created

**EXPIRE_TIME**: the time the key expires, in ISO 8601 format. For example: 2021-12-04T20:12:00+0000

Save and close the file.

Run the gcloud compute instances add-metadata command to set the ssh-keys value:

```
gcloud compute instances add-metadata VM_NAME --metadata-from-file ssh-keys=KEY_FILE
```

Replace the following:

**VM_NAME**: the VM you want to add the SSH key for

**KEY_FILE** with one of the following:

- The path to the file you created in the previous step, if the VM had existing SSH keys
- The path to your new public SSH key file, if the VM didn't have existing SSH keys

Answer (score 0):

1. Generate ssh key in master vm
   `ssh-keygen -o -C "mykey" -f ~/.ssh/id_rsa`
2. then copy the public key in the metadata section in the gcp
3. just make sure while you are connecting to same instance please use that private key

Note: UFW should not be installed